# How to run simultaneously four Python scripts from another scripts

Tags: python-2.7

I ‘m new with the Python world. I have four Python Script, and now during the testing phase, i have to run each of one from differenti console istances. My question is: is possible to create an unique script Python, and from it execute at the same time, the 4 scripts. 
I’am working with a publisher/subscriber architetture, so i have one publisher and three sbuscriber.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I wouldn't run them  from python. Create a batch file (windows) or a bash script(linux) and run all four of them as a background process so that they don't have to wait for each other to complete

Comment: Thanks, can suggest me some examples?

Comment: on a linux system you would create a file called something like run_all.sh
and add the following lines to it   
   
`nohup python script_1.py &`   
`nohup python script_2.py &`   
`nohup python script_3.py &`   
`nohup python script_4.py &`   

Then run 
`chmod +x run_all.sh`  
`./run_all.sh`

Answer (score 0):

In python you can try to use something like this:

```
import os

# list with the name of your scripts

scripts=["script_1.py", "script_2.py","script_3.py"]

for i in range (len(scripts)):
    print "Executing ", scripts[i]
    # string with script parameters
    # in this case they are identical for everyone
    script_parameters="-p parameters"
    # build the command as if you typed it in the terminal
    #
    my_command = "python"+" "+scripts[i]+" "+script_parameters
    print my_command
    # run your command on the operating system
    os.system(my_command)
```

I do not know if this is what you were looking for, but I hope you find it useful